# Ubuntu downloaded on partion on second harddrive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, bios

I just installed Ubuntu on a partion on another disk. Now I am having problems starting ubuntu. I downloaded it alongside windows so right now windows is constantly booting instead of giving me an option. I think it might be that I made a partion inside of my ubuntu partion. I said that this partion would be a bios boot partion with 1mb of memory(those 3 partions you make before you install ubuntu, the root etc). Just looked at my bios and it seems I am using UEFI. Is this the problem? Do I need to empty that partion and download linux again or can I go back and change it somehow?

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: You installed in BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot mode, if you have a bios_grub partition. If Windows is UEFI and hardware is UEFI, you want Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Normally Ubuntu's grub & Windows boot loaders share one ESP on first drive. You can use Boot-Repair with Ubuntu live installer, booted in UEFI boot mode to totally uninstall the BIOS version of grub & install the UEFI version.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  l do like to have an ESP on every drive, but that is just used as a backup for ESP on first drive.

Answer (score 0):

I also installed Ubuntu on a complete separate HDD in one of my PCs. And told Ubuntu installer to also put GRUB on this second HDD.
Now I have to push F12 button at start to select between HDDs to start from.
When I do nothing, PC will boot from first HDD with Windows Boot Loader on it (the Kids use this for gaming).
When I manually select the "hidden HDD", GRUB pops up to boot Ubuntu.

Anyway, I did this on purpose and it requires deviation from the default parameters of Ubuntu Installer :-)

Mayhaps this is the key to your configuration, too?